# Splitting one cell into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

So this is what one of my column looks like :

| Infos |
| --- |
| NAME: ANGELA SURNAME:SMITH AGE:22 CITY: LA |
| NAME: ANDREW SURNAME: D'ONOFRIO AGE:47 CITY: NYC |

I'd like to create four columns :

| NAME | SURNAME | AGE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANGELA | SMITH | 22 | LA |
| ANDREW | D'ONOFRIO | 47 | NYC |

I read that we can use "separate" from tidyverse, and this what i tried.

```
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

df <- infos %>% separate(Infos, c("NAME", "SURNAME","AGE","CITY"))
```

But this is the output :

| NAME | SURNAME | AGE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME | ANGELA | SURNAME | SMITH |
| NAME | ANDREW | SURNAME | D'ONOFRIO |

Then i'd like to understand how to make R knows what it has to separate. Maybe that this exact topic have been treated here before (but i didn't find it) so feel free to redirect me if necessary !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) extract** Use extract with the pattern shown.  The test data did not have any spaces within the contents of the fields but even if it did this should work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pat <- "NAME: *(.*) SURNAME: *(.*) AGE: *(.*) CITY: *(.*)"
dat %>% 
  extract(Infos, c("NAME", "SURNAME", "AGE", "CITY"), pat, convert = TRUE)
##     NAME   SURNAME AGE CITY
## 1 ANGELA     SMITH  22   LA
## 2 ANDREW D'ONOFRIO  47  NYC
```

**2) Base R** Alternately using only base R we get this general solution which will continue to work even if the number of columns or their names change.  This should also work if there are spaces in the contents of the fields. It works by converting Infos into dcf format followed by read.dcf.

```
dat |>
  with(gsub("(\\w+:)", "\n\\1", Infos)) |>
  textConnection() |>
  read.dcf() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
##     NAME   SURNAME AGE CITY
## 1 ANGELA     SMITH  22   LA
## 2 ANDREW D'ONOFRIO  47  NYC
```

### Note

dat in reproducible form:

```
dat <-
structure(list(Infos = c("NAME: ANGELA SURNAME:SMITH AGE:22 CITY: LA", 
"NAME: ANDREW SURNAME: D'ONOFRIO AGE:47 CITY: NYC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

One more strategy

```r
df <- structure(list(Infos = c("NAME: ANGELA SURNAME:SMITH AGE:22 CITY: LA", 
                           "NAME: ANDREW SURNAME: D'ONOFRIO AGE:47 CITY: NYC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                     -2L))
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Infos = gsub('\\:\\s*', ':', Infos)) %>%
  separate_rows(Infos, sep = '\\s') %>%
  separate(Infos, into = c('N', 'V'), sep = ':') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = N, values_from = V, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(everything())
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   NAME   SURNAME   AGE   CITY 
#>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
#> 1 ANGELA SMITH     22    LA   
#> 2 ANDREW D'ONOFRIO 47    NYC
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Base R option using `strcapture` -

```
strcapture('NAME:\\s*(.*)\\s*SURNAME:\\s*(.*)\\s*AGE:\\s*(.*)\\s*CITY:\\s*(.*)', 
           infos$Infos, proto = list(NAME = character(), 
           SURNAME = character(), AGE = numeric(), CITY = character()))

#    NAME    SURNAME  AGE CITY
#1 ANGELA      SMITH   22   LA
#2 ANDREW  D'ONOFRIO   47  NYC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `str_squish`, `str_replace_all` and `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Infos = str_squish(str_replace_all(Infos, ":", " "))) %>% 
  separate(Infos, c("helper1", "Name", "helper2", "Surname", "helper3", "Age", "helper4","City"), sep = " ") %>%
  select(-starts_with("helper"))
```

Output:

```
  Name   Surname   Age   City 
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 ANGELA SMITH     22    LA   
2 ANDREW D'ONOFRIO 47    NYC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert dummy columns, then delete them.

```
tibble(dat=c("NAME: ANGELA SURNAME:SMITH AGE:22 CITY: LA", 
             "NAME: ANDREW SURNAME: DONOFRIO AGE:47 CITY: NYC")) %>% 
    separate(dat, c("DEL1", "NAME", "DEL2", "SURNAME", "DEL3", "AGE", "DEL4", "CITY")) %>% 
    select(-DEL1, -DEL2, -DEL3, -DEL4)
```

> ```
>  NAME   SURNAME  AGE   CITY 
>  ANGELA SMITH    22    LA   
>  ANDREW DONOFRIO 47    NYC
> ```